# Room Database Migration Issue with Alter Table

Tags: android, migration, android-room

First time that I have had to change my database, and after reading some tutorials it seemed straightforward. However, although I have provided a migration I am still getting the following error:
"A migration from 1 to 2 was required but not found. Please provide the necessary Migration path via RoomDatabase.Builder.addMigration(Migration ...) or allow for destructive migrations via one of the RoomDatabase.Builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration* methods."

Version is incremented, migration with alter code in place, addMigration called. I thought that I had done each of the pieces correctly, but something is still not working.

AppDatabase.java

```
@Database(entities = {OwnedCards.class, WantedCards.class}, version = 2, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

public abstract OwnedDao ownedDao();
public abstract WantedDao wantedDao();

private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

public static AppDatabase getDbInstance(Context context) {

    if(INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "my_DB")
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();

    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        // Your migration strategy here
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'owned_cards' ADD COLUMN 'ownedNewQty' INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0");
    }
};
}
```

OwnedCards.java

```
@Entity(tableName = "owned_cards")
public class OwnedCards {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
@NonNull
public String number;

@ColumnInfo(name = "ownedNewQty")
public Integer ownedNewQty;
}
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have some bad SQL. Make sure your SQL syntax is correct and free of errors. It looks like `execSQL()` is failing, causing the migration to fail.

You should be using backticks instead of single quotes.

```
ALTER TABLE
  `owned_cards`
ADD
  COLUMN `ownedNewQty` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Comment: Making this change results in the same error. Some examples don't show backticks or single quotes which I have also tried all with the same result.

Comment: What happens when you annotate `ownedNewQty` with `@NonNull`